# Select / SelectAll delete Not working in PHP MySQL / AJAX Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Good day, I can't seem to understand why this isn't working. I've set up all the files to be able to read from my database, but it just won't delete. I managed to get the select all button to work, but it won't let me delete.

Here's my code.

PHP Delete

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once('dbConfig.php');
if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])){
    $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
    foreach($idArr as $id){
        mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id=".$id);
    }
    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Users have been deleted successfully.';
    header("Location:display.php");
}
?>
```

Here's the data being sent to the display page.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="delete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php session_start(); if(!empty($_SESSION['success_msg'])){ ?>
<div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $_SESSION['success_msg']; ?></div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['success_msg']); } ?>
<?php
include_once('dbConfig.php');
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM appointments");
?>
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "appointments");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '
<form name="bulk_action_form" action="delete_multiple.php" method="post" onSubmit="return delete_confirm();"/>
      <div class="table-responsive">

           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>  
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Email</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Address</th>  
                     <th width="10%">phoneNumber</th>  
                     <th width="10%">appointmentTime</th> 
                     <th width="10%">appointmentDate</th> 
                     <th width="50%">message</th> 
  
                     
                </tr>';  
                             if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                             {  
                                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
                                  {  
                                       $output .= '               
                                    
                <tr data-row-id="'.$row["id"].'">  
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="'.$row["id"].'"/></td>
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                     <td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="email" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                     <td class="address" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                     <td class="phoneNumber" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["phoneNumber"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentTime" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentTime"].'</td>  
                     <td class="appointmentDate" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentDate"].'</td>
                     <td class="message" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["message"].'</td>
                     
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }                                   
                                 
 }  
 else  
 {  

      $output .= '<tr><td colspan="10">Data not Found</td></tr>';  
 }  


 $output .= '</table>
<div align="center">  
                 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="bulk_delete_submit" value="Delete"/>    
                </div>  
      </div>    ';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript

```js
function delete_confirm(){
 var result = confirm("Are you sure to delete users?");
 if(result){
  return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
 
 $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
  if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
   $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
  }else{
   $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
  }
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
 
 $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
  if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
   $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
  }else{
   $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
  }
 });
});
```

Also, if I may.. here's the display page where the JS of the table is found.

```html
<?php
    require("config.php");
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {
        header("Location: success.php");
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
   
    
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Hope Medi Clinic
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="../../appointments/">Main Website</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
                   <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">Appointments</h3><br />  
                    <div id="live_data"></div>
                     <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>  
           </div>  
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    
    <script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      fetch_data();  
      function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"edit.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data){  
                     alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
     /* ............. */
      $(document).on('blur', '.name', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id1");  
           var name = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, name, "name");  
      });  
     
      $(document).on('blur', '.email', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var email = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, email, "email");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.address', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var address = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, address, "address");
            
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.phoneNumber', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var phoneNumber = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, phoneNumber, "phoneNumber");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.appointmentTime', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var appointmentTime = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, appointmentTime, "appointmentTime");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.appointmentDate', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var appointmentDate = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, appointmentDate, "appointmentDate");  
      });
     $(document).on('blur', '.message', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var message = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, message, "message");  
      });
    
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
           var id=$(this).data("id3");  
           if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"delete.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{id:id},  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data){  
                          alert(data);  
                          fetch_data();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });
        
        
 });
    </script>
    

<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please post the result of `print_r($_POST['checked_id[]'])`

Comment: Why did you repeat your script from your third given code? What is the purpose of the AJAX in your last given code if you already have a script for delete confirmation in your third given code? I assume your first given code is `delete_multiple.php`. Where is your button that has a class tag of `btn_delete`?

Comment: @LoganWayne Sorry for the confusion, i forgot to remove that when I pasted my code here. It's actually for a single row delete, and has nothing to do with the multiple delete functionality. As to the button, I removed it from the code..

Comment: you should add a check for errors in the sql. mysqli_error() if the mysqli_query returns false

Comment: also you have no end form tag `</form>`

Comment: try replacing   `$idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
    foreach($idArr as $id){`  with  `foreach($_POST['checked_id'] as $id){ `

Comment: Sorry, didn't include thte </form> close,. @Bender tried, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Questions:**

- Why did you repeat your script from your third given code?
- What is the purpose of the AJAX in your last given code if you already have a script for delete confirmation in your third given code?
- I assume your first given code is `delete_multiple.php`
- Where is your button that has a class tag of `btn_delete`?
- Do you receive any error from you browser's console?

First, lets assume that your `Delete` button below the user's table is for batch deletion. Remove the redundant script and make sure that you include a jQuery file because you are running a jQuery script.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then you want to have a delete button for each row? That is the purpose of your Ajax in your last given code, right?

Lets add a new column for a delete button (single deletion):

```
....
<td class="appointmentDate" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["appointmentDate"].'</td>
<td class="message" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["message"].'</td>
<td><a href="#" data-artid="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
....
```

So that when `btn_delete` is clicked, it will just delete that row:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  

     var elem = $(this),
         id = elem.data("data-artid"); 

     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
     {
         $.ajax({  
             url:"delete.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{id:id},  
             dataType:"text",  
             success:function(data){  
                 elem.closest("tr").hide(200);
             }  
        });  
    }  
});
```

So in your `delete.php`, you will have your delete query:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM appointments WHERE id=".$_POST["id"]);
```

**Suggestions:**

- Use at least `*_real_escape_string()`
- or better yet, use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Sorry sir, i've already answered your questions above. I already have those (didn't include them here). The batch deletion is my concern :) I'm sorry for not making that clear. I'll try your suggestion on the batch delete.

Comment: Also, I updated the third code. I noticed it was lacking, the editor somehow trimmed it earlier. sorry,

Comment: @NathanDeGuia - do you receive any error in your browser's console when you try to a batch deletion?

Comment: I dont get any errors on the console. But I noticed that the button I placed below the table doesn't seem to work. I tried adding a javascript library.

Comment: @NathanDeGuia Inspect your check boxes if they have the proper `value`.

Comment: Thanks man, I got it to work using a tutorial I found over the internet. I found out that this line wasn't needed.  <tr data-row-id="'.$row["id"].'">